# How to execute all requests from log file only once in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Here is the problem, before actually executing my load test I want to prepopulate pages in cache, in order to do that I need to request them only once, they all located in log file.
So, is there is a way to tell Jmeter to execute all requests from file only once?

Comment: Add `Number of Threads = No of requests in the log file` & `Loop Count :1`. If the `Number of threads` is too high then optimization is needed.

Comment: And what if I want to change log file or use different file? It'll be necessary make these calculations again? What I want to do is to make jmeter work in queue mode, not in circular, without calculating how many requests I have in file or smthn like that.